# Generating function from convolution

Tags: combinatorics

I have a generating function $T(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} t_nx^n$ and from a recurrence of $t_n$ I have $\sum_{n \geq 1} t_nx^n = \sum_{n \geq q} 2t_{n-1}x^n + \sum_{n\geq1} (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} t_{k-1}t_{n-k-1})x^n$.  I am having trouble writing the last term in terms of $T(x)$.  I know that if i had $\sum_{n\geq1} (\sum_{k=0}^{n} t_{k}t_{n-k})x^n$ I could rewrite the last term as $T(x)^2$, but I can't seem to make anything happen with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \sum_{n\geq1} (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} t_{k-1}t_{n-k-1})x^n=x \sum_{n\geq1} (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} t_{k-1}t_{n-k-1})x^{n-1}=x \sum_{n\geq 0} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} t_{k-1}t_{n-k})x^{n}=x \sum_{n\geq 0} (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t_{k}t_{n-k+1})x^{n}= x\sum_{n\geq 0} t_nx^{n}\sum_{n\geq 0} t_{n+1}x^{n}=xT(x)\frac{T(x)-T(0)}{x}=T(x)^2-T(x)T(0)$$

I wrote it, like it came to my mind, now that I see what the solution is, there might be a quicker way.